# DAX: Averaging multiple % Columns

Tags: average, powerbi, powerpivot, dax

I'm new to Power BI and Dax, having some difficulty with the below scenario.

```
test    a       b        c       d           AVERAGE
aa              51.97%           46.61%      49%
```

I have 4 columns, a-d, and I simply want the average of the 4 columns in the AVERAGE column. Dependent on the row different columns may be blank. Each of the columns are measures pulling through a % value into the table.

I'm sure there must be a simple solution to this but any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The blank columns could affect the average calculation, is it ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a column like this:

```
AVERAGE = ([a]+[b]+[c]+[d])/4
```

**UPDATE:** BLANK measures don't affect average result.

```
AVERAGE = DIVIDE(([a]+[b]+[c]+[d]),
  (IF(ISBLANK([a]),0,1) + IF(ISBLANK([b]),0,1) + 
   IF(ISBLANK([c]),0,1) + IF(ISBLANK([d]),0,1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had done that originally but I need the average function to only look at entries which are not blank otherwise it will skew the results.

Comment: @ScotCal, I've updated my answer try my second expression.

Comment: @ScotCal, You are welcome, If my answer solved you issue you can [mark it as the correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to positively close the question.